# Using Javascript to remove navbar links to current page. Why does it only work sometimes?

Tags: javascript, function, navigation, include

I am using `include` to load my main navigation and footer onto all the pages of my website. I am attempting to use javascript to, on page load, change the color of the current page's menu item as well as remove the href tag for all main navigation and footer items that would link to the current page. The problem I'm having is that the code I've written only executes properly *sometimes.* When I reload any given page, maybe the header is adjusted but not the footer, maybe nothing is adjusted, or maybe everything is adjusted.

Inside my body I've got the included navigation bar, other code, the included footer, and then the script that calls the JS file. Here's my simplified html.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Website</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    
    <!-- Add jQuery -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 

</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        
    <!-- Load navbar here -->
    <div id="loadnavbar"></div>
                
    ... other code ...
        
    <!-- Load footer here -->
    <div id="loadfooter"></div>
                
    </div>
    
    <script src="js/include-code.js"></script>
    
    <script type="text/javascript" data-currentPage="homenav" data-currentPage2="logonav" data-currentFoot="homefoot" data-currentFoot2="logofoot" src="js/CR-set-menu-current.js"></script>
    
</body> 
</html>
```

I've attached IDs to all my navigation and footer menu item a tags, and I'm passing up to four IDs to the javascript file to color and/or remove hrefs. The include script appear to be working just fine.

```
// JavaScript for including navigation, footer

$.get("html/navbar-include.html", function(data){
    $("#loadnavbar").replaceWith(data);
});

$(function(){
    $("#loadfooter").load("html/footer-include.html"); 
});
```

Below is my included navigation menu. The javascript call in here is to operate the responsive navbar. It is working properly.

```
        
    <!-- Top Navigation Menu -->
    <div class="navimage">
        <nav>
            <ul class="menu">
                <li class="logo"><a href="index.html" id="logonav">
                    <img src="images/logo.svg" alt="logo" id="navlogo" /></a>
                </li>
                <li class="item"><a href="index.html" id="homenav">Home</a></li>
                <li class="item has-submenu">
                    <a tabindex="0" id="productsnav">Products</a>
                    <ul class="submenu">
                        <li class="subitem"><a href="products.html" id="allproductsnav">All Products</a></li>
                        <li class="subitem"><a href="product1.html" id="p1nav">Product 1</a></li>
                        <li class="subitem"><a href="product2.html" id="p2nav">Product 2</a></li>
                        <li class="subitem"><a href="product3.html" id="p3nav">Product 3</a></li>
                        <li class="subitem"><a href="product4.html" id="p4nav">Product 4</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="item"><a href="about.html" id="aboutnav">About</a></li>
                <li class="item"><a href="contact.html" id="contactnav">Contact</a></li>
                <li class="toggle"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    
    <script src="js/navbar-script.js"></script>
```

Here's the included footer.

```
 
    <!-- footer -->
    <div class="footimage">
        <footer>
            <div class="footercolumns">
                <div class="footcolumn">
                    <a href="index.html" id="logofoot"><img src="images/logo.svg" alt="logo"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="footcolumn footspacing">
                        <ul>
                          <li><a href="index.html" id="homefoot">Home</a></li>
                          <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                          <li><a href="contact.html" id="contactfoot">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="footcolumn footspacing">
                        <ul class="foot-menu-spacing">
                          <li><a href="products.html" id="allproductsfoot"><strong>Products:</strong></a></li>
                          <li><a href="product1.html" id="p1foot">Product 1</a></li>
                          <li><a href="product2.html" id="p2foot">Product 2</a></li>
                          <li><a href="product3.html" id="p3foot">Product 3</a></li>
                          <li><a href="product4.html" id="p4foot">Product 4</a></li>
                        </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p class="copyright">Copyright &#169;2023 &ndash; Company &ndash; All Rights Reserved</p>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </div>
```

And finally, here's the javascript.

```
// JavaScript for Menu Manipulation

var this_js_script = $('script[src*=CR-set-menu-current]');

var currentPage = this_js_script.attr('data-currentPage');   
if (typeof currentPage === "undefined") {
    currentPage = 'nohighlight';
}

var currentPage2 = this_js_script.attr('data-currentPage2');
if (typeof currentPage2 === "undefined") {
    currentPage2 = currentPage;
}

var currentFoot = this_js_script.attr('data-currentFoot');
if (typeof currentFoot === "undefined") {
    currentFoot = currentPage;
}

var currentFoot2 = this_js_script.attr('data-currentFoot2');
if (typeof currentFoot2 === "undefined") {
    currentFoot2 = currentFoot;
}

/* Change color of current page navigation menu and submenu items 
   Eliminate current page links in navigation and footer. */
function markCurrentPageInMenu() {
    var currentMenu = document.getElementById(currentPage);
    currentMenu.classList.add("current");
    currentMenu.removeAttribute("href");

    var currentMenu2 = document.getElementById(currentPage2);
    currentMenu2.classList.add("current");
    currentMenu2.removeAttribute("href");

    var currentFootNav = document.getElementById(currentFoot);
    currentFootNav.removeAttribute("href");
    
    var currentFootNav2 = document.getElementById(currentFoot2);
    currentFootNav2.removeAttribute("href");
}

window.addEventListener("load", markCurrentPageInMenu, false);
```

The javascript code is supposed to assign the IDs I passed to the script to variables and then use those variables to change the color of the menu item (.classList.add("current")) and remove the link from the menu and footer items (.removeAttribute("href")). If a variable is not passed (null), the code should assign an alternate value to that variable.

When I added console.log calls throughout the JS, I found that all the variables were being assigned correctly, but problems occurred inside the markCurrentPageInMenu function. Sometimes currentMenu would be set to null and the function wouldn't execute. Sometimes the currentMenu and currentMenu2 steps would execute, but the currentFootNav would show a null value and break the code. Sometimes the entire function would execute just fine. When the entire function executed, the variables inside the function would show the URL of the current page (e.g., currentMenu = https://website.com/test/index.html.)

What am I doing wrong?